# Get random color from list

Tags: c#, random

I have a list filled with colors used to color rectangles and i want to get the color randomly and equally for each color

like if there is 9 rects and R,G,B color

- 3 rect R
- 3 rect G
- 3 rects B

Edit: I couldn't make more than the random part

```
List<Color> rc = new List<Color>();
        rc.Add(Color.Blue);
        rc.Add(Color.Yellow);
        rc.Add(Color.Red);
Random random = new Random(0);                    
Color color = rc[random.Next(rc.Count - 1)];
```

this so far what i came up with 
but how to choose the colors Equally after 9 time for example

Comment: What have you done so far (code, please), and what's throwing you?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to assign the color randomly?  Since you know you want equal color distributions, why not assign the colors up front and then select a rectangle randomly instead.

Comment: @AdamS: nice idea i will use it thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feels a little like a homework question so I won't give you all of the answer :)  But I would create an array that contains the correct distribution of colors and then shuffle that array and color based on those results.

for you example:

Create this array

R,R,R,G,G,G,B,B,B

then shuffle the array (like you shuffle cards you should be able to find sample code online). To get something like this

R,G,G,R,B,G,R,R,G

those are the colors for your rects.

Comment: now you mention it
it really does sound like a homework but actually it's not!!
anyway thanks